# Determining conditional type in IDE in If statement

Tags: typescript, types, react-typescript

With a type specified to have two formats, depending on the value of one of the keys, like so

```
type singleOrMultiValue = {isSingle: true, value: string} | {isSingle: false, set: Array<string>}
```

I can use it to guard against errors like `const val : singleOrMultipleValue = {isSingle: false, value: '1'}`.

But trying to determine what a variable type is at run time, I would try:

```
if (val.isSingle) {
   console.log(val.value)
} else {
   console.log(val.set[0])
}
```

But this will give me error of `value` does not exist on type `singleOrMultiValue` for `{isSingle: false}`. Is there a way to write this so that the IDE understands in this if scope, the type has `isSingle` of value true? Or is the only way to explicitly declare another variable to conform / use `as any`?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDOBLAdgcwDbADyUAsgK54wYBqAhnmagLxwDeGaAytvsAFwIojADRwAbvUYC0MKDwC+cAD5sO3XAQEAzemmCi9MAQEEoUWogA8MubgB88gFDOAxhCwzx9ONJ4Fi5JQ0ksxwJLQwABYAdOZYACYQALYAFACUcHZwAAzRAKxwAPyqXH78giJeDOUA5ACMNYoC7KUa5Tp4egbARnAA2vU1ALpOjhhacCkSeNFqZRmsjnDLbh4QBNF4EDhT9NHTjGmOisCdqIvLcKto68Cb27szhn3ZQ0fyQA

Comment: Hey Titian - I copied the exact code into VS Code and it does give the same warning for `set` does not exist on type. See my answer below on solution.

Comment: You don't have strict null checks turned on then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution- VS Code can recognise the value in an if statement, but only if you write `else if (val.isSingle == false)`, and not `else if (!val.isSingle)` or `else {`.